# How to orchestrate multiple AWS App Runner Services and other AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner

My goal is to host a web application on AWS with App Runner.

I have a project that consists of two Docker images; a front end React app and a FastAPI python back-end API service that work in tandem.

I pushed both Docker images to AWS ECR and plan on creating App Runner Services for both the UI and API images respectively.

My thought process is to create an AWS VPC Endpoint between the two App Runner Services which I believe I did following the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html#create-interface-endpoint).

Similarly I anticipate creating a VPC Endpoint between the API App Runner Service and an AWS RDS instance. Currently I have a postgres image as one of the services in my API `docker-compose.yml`.

A general question I have is does this sound "correct"? Are there better approaches with respect to App Runner?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some drawbacks of things not yet on the Roadmap/not yet implemented for AWS AppRunner I think I have a different course of action.

After reading this Application Architecture guide I plan on trying out ECS since the example they provided in the EC2 Launch Type section mirrors the architecture of my own project; (1) a front end service (2) an API service (3) a datastore. From the page "create task definitions that group the containers that are used for a common purpose, and separate the different components into multiple, separate task definitions"

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/application_architecture.html